# SetupGetInfFileList function is failing with ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER if the directory path is too long

Tags: c++, winapi

Can someone please tell me how to remove the `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` in `SetupGetInfFileList` function when Directory path is long.

TCHAR *aBuffer;
DWORD BufferSize =0 , RequiredSize =0;

```
BOOL bError = SetupGetInfFileList(DirectoryPath, INF_STYLE_WIN4, NULL, BufferSize, &RequiredSize);  //First Call

if (bError == FALSE)
{ 
    if (lastError == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    {
        return RESULT2(ERR_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        return RESULT2(ERR_INI_FILELIST); //My code is giving me Error code 122 here.
    }
}

aBuffer = (TCHAR *)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwRequiredSize * sizeof (TCHAR));

if (aBuffer == NULL)
{
    return RESULT2(ERROR_MEMORY_EXCEPTION);
}

BufferSize = RequiredSize;

aError = SetupGetInfFileList(DirectoryPath, INF_STYLE_WIN4 , aBuffer, BufferSize, NULL);    //Second call

if (aError == FALSE)
{
```

I am getting Error code 122 and RequiredSize varaibale as 0 in the first call only.
Can some suggest me any workaround for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` indicates that the basic problem is that the buffer you provided is too small to hold all the data. Luckily, the function [SetupGetInfFileListA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupgetinffilelista) (and also the [SetupGetInfFileListW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupgetinffilelistw) variant) has the parameter `RequiredSize`:

> If not **NULL**, points to a variable in which this function returns the required size for the buffer pointed to by the *ReturnBuffer* parameter, in characters. This includes the null terminator. If *ReturnBuffer* is specified and the size needed is larger than *ReturnBufferSize*, the function fails and a call to [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) returns ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.

So basically you have to provide that parameter and it tells you how big the buffer has to be. I cannot test this at the moment, but basically it should be something like this:

*(Beware, code is not tested, obviously.)*

```
// initialize buffer and size of it
DWORD bufferSize = ...
PSTR buffer = ...


DWORD requiredSize = 0;
if (SetupGetInfFileListA(NULL, INF_STYLE_WIN4, buffer, bufferSize, &requiredSize) == 0
    && GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
{
    // Buffer is too small.
    // (Re-)Allocate new buffer with at least requiredSize characters,
    // and then try again with new, larger buffer.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry i was not precise the previous time.